# Coq: Recursive Smart Constructors and Sigma types, how to avoid axioms

Tags: coq

I am using a recursive smart constructor to return a sigma type, which includes the property that the type was constructed in a smart way.  This is very basic compared to the smart constructors and number of properties I tend to have, but I am already running into problems.  I was wondering if there is a better way to work with smart constructors and sigma properties.  Here is my current example with the problem I ran into.

We want to represent some nested function calls for a very restricted language, for example:

> and(lt(3, 5), contains("abcd", "bc"))

We represent the parsed ast, like so:

```
Inductive Func: Type :=
  mkFunc:
    forall
    (name: nat)
    (params: list Func)
    (hash: nat),
  Func.
```

We are still using `nat` instead of string to represent the names, please ignore this, this is just for temporary simplicity.
The `hash` field is important, because it is used to efficiently compare functions calls, so that we can reorder and simplify.  For example:

- > and(lt(3, 5), contains("abcd", "bc")) => and(contains("abcd", "bc"), lt(3, 5))
- > and(lt(3, 5), lt(3, 5)) => lt(3, 5)
- > or(and(lt(3, 5), contains("abcd", "bc")), and(contains("abcd", "bc"), lt(3, 5))) => and(contains("abcd", "bc"), lt(3, 5))

For this hash field to mean anything, it needs an associated property that it was constructed using a smart constructor:

```
Definition get_params (x: Func): list Func :=
  match x with
  | mkFunc _ params _ => params
  end.

Definition get_hash (x: Func): nat :=
  match x with
  | mkFunc _ _ hash => hash
  end.

Definition hash_per_elem (state: nat) (x: nat): nat :=
    31 * state + x.

Fixpoint hash_from_func (f: Func): nat :=
  match f with
  | mkFunc name params _ =>
    let name_hashed := 31 * 17 * name in
    let param_hashes := map hash_from_func params in
    fold_left hash_per_elem param_hashes name_hashed
  end.

Inductive IsSmart (f: Func): Prop :=
  | isSmart: forall
      (name: nat)
      (params: list Func)
      (hash: nat)
  , f = mkFunc name params hash
  ->  hash = hash_from_func f
  ->  Forall IsSmart params
  ->  IsSmart f
  .

Ltac destructIsSmart S :=
  let Name := fresh "name" in
  let Params := fresh "params" in
  let Hash := fresh "hash" in
  let Feq := fresh "feq" in
  let Heq := fresh "heq" in
  let HSmarts := fresh "Hsmarts" in
  destruct S as [Name Params Hash Feq Heq HSmarts].

Definition SmartFunc := { func | IsSmart func }.

Ltac destructSmartFunc SF :=
  let F := fresh "f" in
  let S := fresh "s" in
  destruct SF as [F S];
  destructIsSmart S.

Definition get_func (x: SmartFunc): Func :=
  match x with
  | exist _ f p => f
  end.

Definition get_shash (x: SmartFunc): nat :=
  match x with
  | exist _ f p => get_hash f
  end.

Definition hash_from_params (hname: nat) (params: list Func): nat :=
  let param_hashes := map hash_from_func params in
  fold_left hash_per_elem param_hashes hname.

Definition hash_from_sparams (hname: nat) (sparams: list SmartFunc): nat :=
  let param_hashes := map get_shash sparams in
  fold_left hash_per_elem param_hashes hname.

Lemma hash_from_params_is_hash_from_sparams:
  forall (hname: nat) (sparams: list SmartFunc),
    hash_from_sparams hname sparams
    =
    hash_from_params hname (map get_func sparams).
Proof.
(* For the actual proof see https://github.com/katydid/proofs/issues/10 *)
Admitted.

Definition forall_smart_from_sparams
  (sparams: list SmartFunc):
  Forall IsSmart (map get_func sparams).
(* For the actual proof see https://github.com/katydid/proofs/issues/10 *)
Admitted.

Definition smart_from_sparam
  (s: SmartFunc):
  IsSmart (get_func s).
(* For the actual proof see https://github.com/katydid/proofs/issues/10 *)
Admitted.

Definition mkIsSmart (name: nat) (sparams: list SmartFunc):
  IsSmart
    (mkFunc
      name
      (map get_func sparams)
      (hash_from_sparams (31 * 17 * name) sparams)
    ).
(* For the actual proof see https://github.com/katydid/proofs/issues/10 *)
Admitted.

Definition mkSmartFunc (name: nat) (sparams: list SmartFunc): SmartFunc :=
exist
  _
  (mkFunc
    name
    (map get_func sparams)
    (hash_from_sparams
      (31 * 17 * name)
      sparams
    )
  )
  (mkIsSmart
    name
    sparams
  )
.

(*
We can reconstruct our list of SmartFunc again from our list of params and the Forall property.
*)

Fixpoint get_smart_params'
  (params: list Func)
  (smarts: Forall IsSmart params)
  : list SmartFunc.
destruct params as [|p ps].
- exact [].
- apply Forall_cons_iff in smarts.
  destruct smarts as [smart smarts].
  exact (
    (exist _ p smart)
    :: (get_smart_params' ps smarts)
  ).
Defined.

(* But when we try to retreive our forall property about params from our SmartFunc then we get the error. *)

Theorem get_smart_params (s: SmartFunc): { params | Forall IsSmart params }.
destruct s as [f is].
destruct is.
(* Error: Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition IsSmart *)
```

I have seen that it is possible to use `constructive_indefinite_description`, but this uses an axiom.
I was wondering if there was a way to better work with recursive smart constructors and sigma types to avoid needing axioms?

Note in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/katydid/proofs/issues/10) you will find copy and paste-able code, that you can play around with, if that helps.

Comment: Is IsSmart decidable? Try writing a function `WasSmart : Func -> bool` and soundness/completeness proofs `correct f: Bool.Is_True (WasSmart f) <-> IsSmart f`. I find that decidabilty helps simplify a lot of this stuff and avoids axioms. There's also a trick to freshen Opaque decidable propositions. Basically `fresh {f} (p: P f): P f := if decide f is left d then d else p`

Comment: Are you using the `hash` to speed up actual computations on Coq, or are you formalizing some real-world code that uses the `hash`? Is there evidence that this isn't a case of premature optimization?

Comment: I am formalizing real world code that required this optimization to scale. I actually had to do a large rewrite to incorporate this after I left the company. This is now all open source go code at GitHub.com/katydid/katydid

Comment: Yes IsSmart is decidable, good point. I will also try those ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first instantiate the proof-relevant part of the goal using `exists`, leaving you with a goal in `Prop` so you can then destruct hypotheses in `Prop`.

```
exists (get_params f). (* or: apply (exist _ (get_params f)). *)
destruct is.
```

Comment: You can use `exist (get_params f)` instead of your first line.

Comment: Cool thanks I will try that :)

Comment: `exists (get_params f).` worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

#### Some simpler examples to show when we can and cannot destruct a Prop.

###### We can't destruct a Prop, when our goal contains something in Set:

```
Theorem case_and_point_1:
  forall (m: nat), m > 0 -> { n | n > 0 }.
Proof.
intros m H.
Fail induction H.
(*
We can't destruct a Prop, when our goal contains something in Set.
*)
exists 1.
(*
Now we only need to return a Prop (1 > 0), which means we can destruct a Prop.
*)
induction H.
Abort.
```

###### We can't destruct a Prop, when our goal is in Set:

```
Theorem case_and_point_2:
  3 > 2 -> nat.
Proof.
intros H.
Fail induction H.
(*
We can't destruct a Prop, when our goal is in Set.
*)
exact 1.
Qed.
```

###### We can destruct a Prop, when our goal does not contain something in Set, even if it is in Type:

```
Inductive myType: Type :=
  mkMyType: myType.

Inductive myPropOnType (t: myType): Prop :=
  isMyPropOnType: myPropOnType t.

Theorem case_and_point_3:
  3 > 2 -> { t | myPropOnType t }.
Proof.
intros H.
(*
We can destruct a Prop, when our goal does not contain something in Set, even if it is in Type.
*)
induction H.
Abort.
```

###### We can't destruct a Prop, when our goal contains something in Set:

```
Inductive mySet: Set :=
  mkMySet: mySet.

Inductive myPropOnSet (s: mySet): Prop :=
  isMyPropOnSet: myPropOnSet s.

Theorem case_and_point_4:
  3 > 2 -> { s | myPropOnSet s }.
Proof.
intros H.
(*
We can't destruct a Prop, when our goal contains something in Set:
*)
Fail induction H.
Abort.
```

###### We can destruct a Prop, if it is guaranteed to only return a Prop.

```
Theorem case_and_point_6:
  3 > 2 /\ 1 > 0 -> nat.
Proof.
intros H.
(*
We can destruct a Prop, if it is guaranteed to only return a Prop.
This works for conjunction, which is made up of two props,
but will fail for Forall, which can possibly destruct to the empty list, which is in Set.
*)
destruct H as [H0 H1].
Fail destruct H0.
exact 1.
Qed.
```

###### We can use theorems to destruct a Prop other Props.

````
Lemma seven:
  3 > 2 /\ 1 > 0 -> 7 = 7.
Admitted.

Theorem case_and_point_7:
  3 > 2 /\ 1 > 0 -> nat.
Proof.
intros H.
(*
We can use theorems to destruct a Prop other Props.
*)
apply seven in H.
Abort.
```
````